# Template for Software Release Notes

Tags: templates

Is there a good template for software release notes? I typically cover new features, bug fixes, and enhancements. I'm currently using HTML but its ugly and not easy to distribute. Ultimately, I'd like to produce a single PDF.

Comment: Related question: [Software Requirements Specification with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42602/software-requirements-specification-with-latex)